# Changing element value with BeautifulSoup returns empty element

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

xml_data = """
<doc>
  <test>test</test>
  <foo:bar>Hello world!</foo:bar>
</doc>
"""

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_data)
print soup.prettify()
make = soup.find('foo:bar')
print make
# prints <foo:bar>Hello world!</foo:bar>

make.contents = ['Top of the world Ma!']
print make
# prints <foo:bar></foo:bar>
```

How do I change the content of the element, in this case the element in the variable "make", without loosing the content? If you could point me to other pure python modules which can modify existing xml-documents, please let me know.

PS! BeautifulSoup is great for screenscraping and parsing of both HTML and XML!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [documentation on `replaceWith`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another). This works:

```
make.contents[0].replaceWith('Top of the world Ma!')
```

Comment: My 2 cents I didn't see in the documentation but it seems that the variable "make" only points to the first element found meeting this criteria make = soup.find('foo:bar'). When this variable is modified by the replaceWith(), the original xml_data string  reflects this change.  For some reason I thought the string xml_data was immutable. This is good.

Answer (score 5):

Using BeautifulSoup version 4 (`bs4`), you can achieve the same by [updating `string` property](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string) directly :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_data = """
<doc>
  <test>test</test>
  <foo:bar>Hello world!</foo:bar>
  <parent>Hello <child>world!</child></parent>
</doc>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data)
make = soup.find('foo:bar')

make.string = 'Top of the world Ma!'
print make
# prints <foo:bar>Top of the world Ma!</foo:bar>
```

This approach works well for the case when the element contains other elements, and you want to replace the entire content with a new one :

```
parent = soup.find('parent')
parent.string = 'Top of the world Ma!'

print parent
# prints <parent>Top of the world Ma!</parent>
```

<sub>I bumped into this rather old question just now, and the solution provided was not quite suitable for me. Further research leads me to the above approach, and I thought it maybe useful to share what I ended up using here.</sub>