# Python - download and save the complete web pages

Tags: python-3.x, download, web-crawler, urllib

I have crawled a website and extracted some url's which I need to download and save in my local machine:

And i am using following code to do so:

```
for dept in deptlist:
    i=0
    thisurl = "http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode="+dept
    if not os.path.isdir(dept):
        os.makedirs(dept)
    os.chdir(dept)
    print(os.getcwd())
    # print(thisurl)
    response1 = requests.get(thisurl)
    # print(response.content)
    soup1=BeautifulSoup(response1.content)
    # print(soup.prettify())

    p = re.compile('^/fac-profiles/*')
    links1=soup1.find_all("a")
    for link in links1:
        if p.match(link.get("href")):
            # print("http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/%s" %(link.get("href")))
            url2d="http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/"+link.get("href")
            filename=""+str(i)+".html"
            print(filename)
            print(url2d)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url2d,filename)
            i=i+1
    os.chdir("..")
```

but this does not download the whole webpage no css files nothing so When I open the html pages It is appearing blank.
Please can some one suggest a better method to do so??

Comment: Have you tried downloading the websites dependencies (keeping their relative paths)?. They're listed in the `<head>` of the website. 

The website works when chrome downloads it (Pressing Ctrl + S on the website).

Comment: @bobsterman I have downloaded the files now but the problem is that the html file contains path relative to web directory structure and I need to change it to my local machine directory structure.
Is there nay way to do so without traversing the whole file???

Comment: Relative folder structures should still work on the local filesystem, where the root is the location where the html file is. If that doesnt work, you can [use beautiful soup to change the paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711376/changing-element-value-with-beautifulsoup-returns-empty-element) to the css files paths.